# Effects of loss of oil pressure after oil change

Tags: oil, oil-change, lubrication, oil-filter

I'm curious some people say change oil every 3k miles, 6k, 10k and some even every 20k.

What seams best for the engine and give the best protection would be the shortest interval 3k however I understand what after an oil and filter change when the vehicle is started it runs without lubrication until oil is sucked up through the new filter passed the anti-drain back valve.

How much damage does this actually cause? it must feel like a mini heart attack on the engine.

I don't really know how wear can be measured in this way so put it this way, by changing the oil and running without lubrication for a brief few seconds how many miles would be taken from the engines life? 10miles 100miles, etc.

Thank you all for your time look forward to seeing your opinions.

Comment: There is no way to answer this question. It will be different for *every* engine, even engines which are built the same. Know that damage, while occurring is usually minimal, mainly because oil sticks to the surfaces, especially between surfaces like bearings. Oil's main job is to reduce friction (it has many other jobs as well). During the brief running of the engine, there is very little friction which is occurring, so the bearing life is not diminished by *that much*. There would be no way to put a quantitative number on any of this.

Comment: I think there is a general possible response.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, my apologies I understand it will be difficult to put a number on such things what I should have asked is can shorter service intervals possibly cause more damage than good.

Comment: You can prevent the heart attack on most cars by filling the new oil filter (or it's housing) with oil before installing

Answer (score -1):

You can change your oil every 3 months if you desire.  This will not damage your vehicle system.  It's a good idea to fill your oil filter as completely as possible before installing the new Oil filter.  This could help to avoid air gaps in your oil flow.